# VBA - Select new created row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and need some assistance.

I created a new row with

```
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Now, how do I select the new row for `iRow =`?

Comment: You [do not need to select](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683). If you are wondering about the index of the new row, that would be immediately above the one you used `Insert` against.

Answer (score 0):

first thing off: always avoid `Select`/`Selection` and `Activate`/`ActiveXXX`

that being said, and having no clues of how differently refer to the `ActiveCell`, code like follows:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert '<--| insert new line just below currently active cell
```

and then

```
irow = ActiveCell.Row + 1 '<--! get the row of the ActiveCell and add 1 to it
```

Comment: You are welcome. Then please answer as accepted, thank you.